# Fluentd stops pushing the logs to ES "failed to flush the buffer.could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, buffer, fluent

Fluentd was able to push logs to elasticsearch well , but from past 2 days after restarting the daemon set it sending logs but after an hour it stops throws and error .`

```
failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=6 next_retry_seconds=2023-05-20 08:36:18 +0000 chunk="5fc1bceefb80e1d0b2c5a5d40fc9c619" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::RecoverableRequestFailure error="could not push logs to Elasticsearch cluster ({:host=>\"10.90.42.244\", :port=>9200, :scheme=>\"http\"}): connect_write timeout reached"
```

```
  elastic-fluent.conf: |-
    <match kubernetes.var.log.containers.**pds-cnnfr-mrc**.log>
      @type elasticsearch
      host "10.90.42.244"
      port "9200"
      scheme "http"
      ssl_verify "false"
      index_name "pds-cnnfr-use1"
      include_tag_key true
      request_timeout "60s"
      <buffer>
        @type file
        path /var/mrc-logs.buffer
        flush_thread_count 30
        flush_interval 60s
      </buffer>
    </match>
```

I tried modifying buffer multiple time finally moved flush interval to 60s , again it worked for 4 to 5 hours and henceforth same issue started, rest index are working fine only this particulat indexing is throwing error.

Comment: Can someone please suggest